# Sum of divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $A$ denote a polynomial on $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and $\sigma(A)$ denote the sum of divisors on $A$. Let$$A = x^h(x + 1)^k P^l Q^{2n - 1},$$where $P$, $Q$ are irreducible polynomials with degree at least $2$, $l \neq 2^r - 1$. If $\sigma(A) = A$, how do I see that $2n - 1 = 2^s - 1$?